# Resizing Foundation Zurb Icons

Tags: html, css, zurb-foundation

I have foundation icons installed on my rails app I and am getting the icons but they are showing really small.  Does anyone know how to resize the icons?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the Foundation Icons are fonts you can resize them by setting the font-size of the element that you have applied the icon class to.

For example:

HTML

```
<i class="fi-heart"></i>
```

CSS

```
i {
  font-size: 68px;
}
```